# Click to get index of array element with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

Ok, I've tried my best at searching, but.
I've got a task, where I need to load some js using the Ajax and so on. Long story short, I've stuck.

First a code in script.js (which I must load AND which I can't modify):

```
var divs = [
    '<div class="item">Lorem ipsum 0</div>',
    '<div class="item">Lorem ipsum 1</div>',
    '<div class="item">Lorem ipsum 2</div>',
    '<div class="item">Lorem ipsum 3</div>',
    '<div class="item">Lorem ipsum 4</div>',
    '<div class="item">Lorem ipsum 5</div>',
    '<div class="item">Lorem ipsum 6</div>',
    '<div class="item">Lorem ipsum 7</div>'
];
delete(divs[3]);
```

Then my script to load it

```
$.getScript('script.js', function() {
    $('.a').append('<div class="yep">' + divs.join('') + '</div>');
    $('.item').each(function() {
        $(this).click(function() {
            console.log( $('.item').index(this) );
        });
    });     
});
```

The problem is that on click I need to get index of item in array, i.e. if I click on "Lorem ipsum 4" console should print "4", not "3" as it happens now (because of deleted element which doesn't appear in dom).
Is there a way to get the right result using jQuery?

**Ok, I need to say that it's a task. And here is the thing: I simply CAN'T modify script.js. Let's say it's on server and I have no access to it until I get it. But I need index of an element which it has in the original array.**

Comment: One potential solution would be to store the index with the div element in a data attribute, like so: `<div class="item" data-index="3">Lorem Ipsum 3</div>`

Comment: Yea, you would need an alternative solution. Because the div was deleted before you ran a .each(); that element and its index is gone. You would have to save it another way like with a data-attribute as mentioned above.

Comment: I can't modify the script.js file and I don't need to remove items from array. I need to get the right index only

Comment: @Blazemonger and he's calling it as a function, i'll assume that's psuedocode and delete my previous comment :P

Comment: @jbabey That's unimportant. Doesn't it just set the index's value to undefined and not remove it from the array? Therefore it won't be inserted into the DOM. Anyways, they said they cannot modify that part anyways...

Comment: Please tell us more about what `script.js` ACTUALLY has inside. I'm 99% sure that your example code isn't meant to be used in production.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/YjNAL/1/

```
var divs = [
    '<div class="item">Lorem ipsum 0</div>',
    '<div class="item">Lorem ipsum 1</div>',
    '<div class="item">Lorem ipsum 2</div>',
    '<div class="item">Lorem ipsum 3</div>',
    '<div class="item">Lorem ipsum 4</div>',
    '<div class="item">Lorem ipsum 5</div>',
    '<div class="item">Lorem ipsum 6</div>',
    '<div class="item">Lorem ipsum 7</div>'
];
delete(divs[3]);

var yep = $('<div class="yep"></div>');    // Changed (from edit)

for (var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
    if (divs[i]) {  // Don't operate on undefined items
        var theDiv = $(divs[i]).data("idx", i);    // Changed (from edit)

        yep.append(theDiv);    // Changed (from edit)
    }
}

$(".a").append(yep);    // Changed (from edit)

$('.item').on("click", function() {
    console.log( $(this).data("idx") );
});
```

Notice how the original array isn't modified.

Each item in the array is modified and creates a jQuery object before it is appended. <- I'm sure that part could be done more efficiently, I was just trying to throw something together.

It stores its index in the array from of the `for` loop, so that should be accurate.

Any undefined (deleted) items are ignored.

Comment: Ok, +1 for ingenuity. I hope that's what the OP's real code is doing, though.

Comment: @Blazemonger Thanks :) It's the only way I could think of not touching the first block of code in the OP yet still preserve the index without any unreliable hack. There's still alterations that could be made. And true, who knows what's actually being used...it could be much tougher to do

Comment: @AlexeyKibin No problem! I actually went back through and changed a few things (put a comment on the lines I changed). I realized I did things weird/wrong (mainly actually including the `.yep` div at all), but hopefully it should work just the same but maybe better/correct

Comment: @AlexeyKibin Also, something to possibly optimize it would be instead of binding a `click` event to every `.item` div, is to bind it to the `.yep` divs and delegate it. Like `$(".yep").on("click", ".item", function () { console.log($(this).data("idx")); });`

Answer (score 4):

You're asking for the INDEX of the clicked item. Your code is doing exactly what it's supposed to do. jQuery has no way to know if you've deleted items from the original list, it can only see what's currently there.

The best solution is to add an HTML attribute to the original items, and `console.log` that attribute instead of the `.index`. Like this:

```
var divs = [
    '<div data-idx="0" class="item">Lorem ipsum 0</div>',
    '<div data-idx="1" class="item">Lorem ipsum 1</div>',
    '<div data-idx="2" class="item">Lorem ipsum 2</div>',
    '<div data-idx="3" class="item">Lorem ipsum 3</div>',
    '<div data-idx="4" class="item">Lorem ipsum 4</div>',
    '<div data-idx="5" class="item">Lorem ipsum 5</div>',
    '<div data-idx="6" class="item">Lorem ipsum 6</div>',
    '<div data-idx="7" class="item">Lorem ipsum 7</div>'
    ];
delete(divs[3]);


$('.a').append('<div class="yep">' + divs.join('') + '</div>');

$('.item').each(function() {
    $(this).click(function() {
        console.log($(this).data('idx'));
    });
});​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/8NLGm/

Comment: There's no way for YOUR code to know what's been deleted from the array before you have access to it. You need SOMETHING to go on. We could parse the `.text()` of your divs to extract the number, but I doubt that's the content you're really using.

Answer (score -1):

You can [try this](http://jsfiddle.net/M2zKD/1/). Give all the divs an ID, and get that:

```
var divs = [
    '<div class="item" id="0">Lorem ipsum 0</div>',
    '<div class="item" id="1">Lorem ipsum 1</div>',
    '<div class="item" id="2">Lorem ipsum 2</div>',
    '<div class="item" id="3">Lorem ipsum 3</div>',
    '<div class="item" id="4">Lorem ipsum 4</div>',
    '<div class="item" id="5">Lorem ipsum 5</div>',
    '<div class="item" id="6">Lorem ipsum 6</div>',
    '<div class="item" id="7">Lorem ipsum 7</div>'
];
delete(divs[3]);

$('.a').append('<div class="yep">' + divs.join('') + '</div>');
$('.item').each(function() {
    $(this).click(function() {
        console.log(this.id);
    });
});  ​
```

**Numbers in id's?!?**

Yea, I know, in HTML4 `id`s starting with numbers weren't allowed. HTML5, however, removed this restriction.
Those divs will validate according to the [w3 validator](http://validator.w3.org).

Comment: Nitpick: IDs that start with numbers are invalid HTML 4, although they usually work in browsers anyway.

Comment: It's pretty simple: `this` is the clicked element. `this.id` is that element's `id`, as set in `id="0"` ect.
@Blazemonger: I have yet to see a browser that can't deal with id's that start with numbers.
If whomever downvoted me would give a proper reason why, maybe I can learn from it.

Comment: @AlexeyKibin The proper way to store arbitrary data is with the `data-*` attributes like Blazemonger's answer...please use that solution.

Comment: Hm. You've changed it.
Previous: console.log($(this).text()[$(this).text().length-1]);
Worked for me.

And I couldn't accept it because of site restrictions

Comment: Actually, @Ian, I wouldn't call this "arbitrary data". It's a identifier for the clicked `div`. Textbook `id` use, even though html4 doesn't like numbers in thre. (HTML5, however, removed the "can't start with numbers" restriction)

Comment: @AlexeyKibin: That previous one was pretty much a hack to get it to work, by taking the last character out of the div's text. That's why I changed it, but this still works.

Comment: It's not an identifier in any way that it's meant to be. Does it identify it within the DOM? Then no, it's not an identifier. `id` is the last place you should look to use for this kind of thing

Comment: @Cerbrus The problem in using a simple number for an ID is that there's a reasonable chance some other element on the page will also use that simple number as a unique ID. IDs must be unique. `data-` attributes don't have this restriction.

Answer (score -1):

If you would rather have it a bit dynamic, you could create an element, add a data field to it, then access that element:

```
var divs = [
    '<div class="item">Lorem ipsum 0</div>',
    '<div class="item">Lorem ipsum 1</div>',
    '<div class="item">Lorem ipsum 2</div>',
    '<div class="item">Lorem ipsum 3</div>',
    '<div class="item">Lorem ipsum 4</div>',
    '<div class="item">Lorem ipsum 5</div>',
    '<div class="item">Lorem ipsum 6</div>',
    '<div class="item">Lorem ipsum 7</div>'
    ];
var newdivs = $('<div class="yep">').append(divs.join(""));
newdivs.find('.item').each(function() {
     $(this).data("myindex", $(this).index());
});
var elementToDelete = 3
delete(divs[elementToDelete]);
newdivs.find('.item').eq(elementToDelete).remove();
$('.a').append(newdivs);

$('.a').on('click','.item',function() {
    $(this).css("background-color","lime");
    alert($(this).data("myindex"));
});
```

see how it works here:
http://jsfiddle.net/rZjNd/2/

Comment: That fiddle's alerting `undefined` for me. (Google Chrome)

Comment: Fixed it, was a syntax issue on a refactor of mine :)

Comment: In this solution I need to change original script, which I can't do